# pandas update a dataframe column based on prefiltered groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

given dataframe `d` such as this:

> ```
>  index  col1
>   1      a 
>   2      a
>   3      b
>   4      b
> ```

Create a prefiltered group object with new values:
`g = d[prefilter].groupby(['some cols']).apply( somefunc )`

```
  index  col1
  2      c
  4      d
```

Now I want to update df to this:

```
   index   col1
    1      a
    2      c
    3      b
    4      d
```

Ive been hacking away with update, ix, filtering, where, etc...  I am guessing there is an obvious solution I am not seeing here.
stuff like this is not working:

```
 d[d.index == db.index]['alert_v'] = db['alert_v']

 q90 = g.transform( somefunc )
 d.ix[ d['alert_v'] >=q90, 'alert_v'] = 1
 d.ix[ d['alert_v'] < q90, 'alert_v'] = 0

  d['alert_v'] = np.where( d.index==db.index, db['alert_v'], d['alert_v'] )
```

any help is appreciated

thankyou

--edit--
the two dataframes are in the same form:
one is simply a filtered version of the other, with different values, that I want to update to the original.

`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 2186 entries, 1984-12-12 13:33:00 to 1939-03-19 22:54:00
Data columns (total 9 columns):
source        2186 non-null object
subject_id    2186 non-null float64
alert_t       2186 non-null object
variable      2186 non-null object
timeindex     2186 non-null datetime64[ns]
alert_v       2105 non-null float64
value         2186 non-null float64
tavg          54 non-null timedelta64[ns]
iqt           61 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(3), object(4), timedelta64[ns](1)None<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

`DatetimeIndex: 1982 entries, 1984-12-12 13:33:00 to 1939-03-19 22:54:00
Data columns (total 9 columns):
source        1982 non-null object
subject_id    1982 non-null float64
alert_t       1982 non-null object
variable      1982 non-null object
timeindex     1982 non-null datetime64[ns]
alert_v       1982 non-null int64
value         1982 non-null float64
tavg          0 non-null timedelta64[ns]
iqt           0 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(2), int64(1), object(4), timedelta64[ns](1)None`

Comment: is it a column called "index"? maybe you can try set_index('index'), and then use .loc() for indexing

Answer (score 0):

you want the df.update() function.

Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Index':[1,2,3,4],'Col1':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']}).set_index('Index')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Index':[2,4],'Col1':['E', 'F']}).set_index('Index')

print df1



    Col1
Index     
1        A
2        B
3        C
4        D

df1.update(df2)

print df1

    Col1
Index     
1        A
2        E
3        C
4        F
```

Comment: yeah, i tried that, it gives ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis  do you know what this is about?  reset_index before update gives same err

Comment: Can you make sure the index on both of your dataframes are the same?  The example I did above works, so it's just a matter of getting your two frames to be in the same format of df1 and df2.